# How to use single button for different functionality in FLUTTER?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made an Elevated Button for a screen, but I want the same button for another screen, but I want to change its properties for the other screen, e.g
its COLOR, its TEXT, its FUNCTIONALITY. Although I have made another class for that, I'm lacking knowledge for Functionality purposes.

```dart
 ElevatedButton(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size(500,70),
                primary: Colors.white12,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),),
              ),

              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ThirdScreen()),
                );
              },

              child: Text('Log in',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),

            )
```

Comment: you are trying archive same button UI through the app?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a CustomButton like this. You can just copy and paste this code in your project and it will work. Try to set other parameters to try out and get the custom look you want:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const FirstScreen());

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Hello World',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Center(
          // Use the CustomButton as a child and fill
          // it's parameters.
          child: CustomButton(
            color: Colors.white12,
            text: 'Log in',
            function: () async {
              await Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute<Widget>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return const SecondScreen();
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare the variables you want your custom
  // button to have.
  final Color color;
  final String text;
  final VoidCallback function;

  const CustomButton({
    super.key,
    required this.color,
    required this.text,
    required this.function,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: function,
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        minimumSize: const Size(500, 70),
        backgroundColor: color,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Placeholder(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Widget like this and use anywhere you want:

```dart
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  final Widget text;
  final Function onTap;

  const MyButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.color,
    required this.text,
    required this.onTap,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => onTap(),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: color,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: text,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Custom widget(including necessary parameters) that will return your customized `ElevatedButton` and used this widget in replace of `ElevatedButton`.

```dart
class MyElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyElevatedButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        minimumSize: const Size(500, 70),
        primary: color,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use like

```dart
MyElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  color: Colors.green,
  text: "Log in",
)
```

Another option is providing `elevatedButtonTheme` on `MaterialApp`

```dart
return MaterialApp(
    theme: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
      elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
            //..
            ),
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

firs you have to declaring a function-type field to button onTap call back in your class before the class name

```
typedef OnButtonClick = Function();
```

after that inside your class you have to create a static method which return a elevated button as widget with input parameters as you want, like color title etc... and also OnButtonClick call back which created at first

```
class Utilities {
  static Widget myButton(OnButtonClick onTap, Color buttonColor, String title) {
    return ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: onTap,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: buttonColor),
        child: Text(title));
     }
  }
```

now you can use this button anywhere you would like with different parameters and functionality

for example i have use it for navigate between to screens.

```
    class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Utilities.myButton(
                () => Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen())),
                Colors.blue,
                "move to second page"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Utilities.myButton(
                () => Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FirstScreen())),
                Colors.red,
                "back to first page"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

full code :

```
   typedef OnButtonClick = Function();

    class Utilities {
      static Widget myButton(OnButtonClick onTap, Color buttonColor, String title) {
        return ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: onTap,
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: buttonColor),
            child: Text(title));
      }
    }


    class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Utilities.myButton(
                () => Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const SecondScreen())),
                Colors.blue,
                "move to second page"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Utilities.myButton(
                () => Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FirstScreen())),
                Colors.red,
                "back to first page"),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```